# Is there a complete guide to which questions you can ask here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm having difficulty asking questions, either because the questions I want to ask have already been taken, or I'm confused on what I can and can't ask.

Is there a list of what types of questions are acceptable on PLDI?

Comment: A comprehensive list would defeat the point, wouldn't it? People would copy-paste from that list and exhaust it.

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking... I'll clarify the question.

Comment: see the [meta-tag:on-topic] tag.

Answer (score 6):

We don't have such a guide yet; the site is in private beta and there are still discussions (on meta and in the chat room) about what should or shouldn't be allowed. When the community has agreed on what questions are on-topic here, then the guide you're looking for will presumably be available in the help pages, [here](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

In the mean-time, if you have a question you want to ask but you're not sure it's appropriate, a good thing to do is ask a question on meta or in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146046/the-garbage-collector).